# How to make a reference parameter in a function optional (optional buffer)

Tags: c++, reference, default

So I'm making a function that detects collisions between two sprites, and would like to add two buffers as optional parameters to be filled with the angle of the sides of each objects collision.

**However this means the two buff parameters must be references, and must be there whenever the function is called, and I am not aware of any way to make a default reference. How can I do this?**

Here's the actual function:

```
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T* obj2, float& CollBuff1= new float, float& CollBuff2= new float);
```

I tried to make a default with 'new' but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can overload the function. Just define a second wrapper function like so:

```
bool CheckCollision(T *obj1, T *obj2)
{
    float dummy1, dummy2;
    return CheckCollision(obj1, obj2, dummy1, dummy2);
}
```

And define a second one for when only one float is provided, if you like.

Answer (score 4):

With [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/), no pointers and no boilerplate overloading:

```
bool CheckCollision(
    T* obj1, T* obj2,
    boost::optional<float&> CollBuff1 = boost::optional<float&>(),
    boost::optional<float&> CollBuff2 = boost::optional<float&>()
);
```

You can test whether you've got the argument by doing `if (CollBuff1)`, and then access the reference with `CollBuff1.get()` (and the other one the same way, obviously).

Comment: Or simply dereference the `CollBuff`: `float& buf1 = *CollBuff1;`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (and very ugly) way to do this would be this:

```
#include <memory>

void test(int a, int& b = *std::auto_ptr<int>(new int())) {
     // ...
}
```

or in your case

```
#include <memory>

bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T* obj2,
    float& CollBuff1= *std::auto_ptr<float>(new float()),
    float& CollBuff2= *std::auto_ptr<float>(new float()));
```

Answer (score 0):

A now deleted (why?) answer from @James McNellis points out the correct solution: You don't.

Use pointers for this, as those buffers are obviously out-parameters (i.e., they're used to "return" additional values) and call it accordingly:

```
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T* obj2, float* ColBuf1 = 0, float* ColBuf2 = 0){
  // your code...
  // ...
  // test before assigning:
  if(ColBuf1 != 0)
    *ColBuf1 = /*whatever you have*/;
  // same with ColBuf2
}

float ColBuf1, ColBuf2;
CheckCollision(SomeObjPtr, AnotherObjPtr, &ColBuf1, &ColBuf2);
```

Or, even better, overload it:

```
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T* obj2);
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T* obj2, float* ColBuf1, float* ColBuf2);
```

Though I'd still use pointers to indicate that those buffers are going to be filled.

Comment: Why pointers? Non-const references also indicate that the parameters can be modified.

Comment: @Bo: I find pointers to stand out more (`&somebuf`) and it directly tells you *I am going to fill this*. Also, it's nullable.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you have in trying to define a default value for a reference parameter is that a non-const reference can't be bound to a temporary object or a literal.

```
void foo(float &f = 1.0f) {} // doesn't compile
void foo(const float &f = 1) {} // OK
```

In fact this is legal:

```
void foo(float &f = *(new float(1))) {}
```

But it's rather inadvisable. The code in the function can't tell whether it was called with the default parameter or not, so you've created a rather unpleasant resource-handling problem for yourself: who is going to `delete` that float, and what will that code do in the case where the caller *did* pass something? bdonlan's overload is preferable.